# GetKeyDown or GetKey doesn't work, sends an error message instead. (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

When i use `GetKeyDown` i get the following:

Non-invocable member 'KeyCode' cannot be used like a method.

Here is the code:

```
 if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode("Space")))
     {
         Debug.Log("Space pressed");
     }
```

Comment: The documentation has examples that should work for you. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html

Answer (score 1):

`KeyCode` is an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) not a method. Replace the `("Space")` with `.Space`.

### Modified version of your code

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    Debug.Log("Space pressed");
}
```